# What does "Yet" mean in here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> But since China signed up to the U.N.'s toughest sanctions against North Korea *yet* in March, after Pyongyang's fourth nuclear test, the daily caravan of trucks rumbling over Dandong's iron bridge from the North has slowed to a trickle.

My question is:How to explain "yet" in the paragraph cited from Time above?
Does it mean "again"?
But I can't find any record shows that China had done this to North Korea before.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [yet](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yet), you can see that it means:

> Up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then.

In the case of your example sentence, *yet* is part of the larger phrase:

> toughest sanctions against North Korea yet

Simply meaning

> toughest sanctions to have ever been placed on North Korea

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that!Thank you very much.

Comment: I checked the word before posting the question, just didn't seem to fit any of definitions. I kept focusing on "yet in March" instead of "toughest...yet". Haha! Thank you for your explanation. It's very clear!

Comment: Jasmine, I can well believe you didn't see it! I'm a native speaker, and I was convinced this was an error until I read FatMan's answer. I had been parsing the sentence to associate "Yet" with  "in March"; completely missed the possibility of "toughest sanctions yet". I don't believe that this is a well-constructed sentence.

Comment: Really? thought that was my own reading problem. Turns out it wasn't!Thank you Djna!!!

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence's word order is a little confusing.

> But since China signed up to the U.N.'s toughest sanctions against
>   North Korea yet in March...

Let's move "in March" and reposition "yet".

**But since China signed up in March to the UN's toughest sanctions yet against North Korea...**

These are the "toughest sanctions yet" or "the toughest sanctions *to date*".

**Yet** modifies "toughest" (or the predicate that they are the toughest). These sanctions are the *toughest yet*, the *toughest to date*.